# mfc drag-and-drop does not work on unicode debug build

Tags: unicode, mfc, drag-and-drop

I have a MFC MDI application that uses drag & drop internally to drop some names in a listbox on to a view where data corresponding those names is plotted.  I have made my own class derived from CListBox that creates a `COleDataSource` object and calls `COleDataSource::OnDragDrop()` inside its `OnMouseMove()`.  The View implements `OnDrop()` and plots the appropriate data.  This has worked properly till now without any problems.

The application was originally not in unicode.

We recently migrated to VS2013 and saw that microsoft is deprecating non-unicode MFC builds.  We too were attracted by the beautiful controls and migrated our application to unicode.  After much `_T()` and `CT2A()` macro insertions the project built and ran successfully.  The only issue is that drag and drop simply does not work on debug builds.  It seems even drag is not started since the cursor does not change.  On release builds it works fine.  Google has been of no help.  Has anybody faced a similar issue?